# How to create multiple columns of links with each column below a tile in promoted links?

Tags: list, page-layout, site-column, team-sites, promoted-links

My question is 2 part -

1. How do I create 4 columns of links on my team page?

For example,

[image]

The lines are only there because I used .xls to show the order.

2. If these are doable, how do I line them up underneath the promoted links so that they "appear" to be corresponding to each tile?

For example,

[image]

I looked and looked and just couldn't figure out how to implement it. The users really want information to be displayed this way.

Can someone please help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options:

- The easiest option is to use a table to align the columns and populate with links.
- The second option is to edit the HTML of the page and add in your own CSS.
- The third option is to use a list to manage the links, add the list to your page and use JSLink to change the display of the list into the columns you need.

Sorry, I don't have any links for you as I'm on my phone but if you search JSLink etc there is a ton of content.

Comment: I used the first option to create the table. It worked well until I started to resize the browser.

Is there a way to resize the table in relation to the promoted links tiles above so that they move in proportion?